# Does it still make sense to normalize data (1NF)? (what's wrong with having empty fields in a table?)

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, normalization, denormalization

Given that disk space is cheap, does it make sense to [normalize data (1NF)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form) rather than store it all in one place for faster queries?

Background:

1. We have a table of users - event organizers and event attendees
2. Both have some common fields, but organizers have many more fields
3. Attendees are far more numerous than organizers on the site

Question: (In the far past) We combined the separate tables which existed and made them into one similar to the following:

```
   Table_Users
   UID, Name, Email, CommonField1, OrgSpecificField1, OrgSpecificField2
```

Now, we have only one common table for both types of users. For attendees, the last two fields are NULL.

Compare the above structure to:

```
   Table_Users
   UID, Name, Email, CommonField1

   Table_UsersOrganizers
   UID, OrgSpecificField1, OrgSpecificField2
```

which would necessitate a JOIN. Now, from the site speed perspective, which would be faster to retrieve - the common-integrated table or the separated one? Remember that we would be constantly fetching these records.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are talking about the site speed in fetching data, then it is definitely the second choice (the separated table)
The data retrieving time is **mainly about the number of entries in the table** (number of rows) which will be less in the separated ones

Answer (score 1):

Normalization is about data integrity - accurately representing the reality that you are trying to model. It has nothing to do with the cost of disk space. Aim to be be in at least Boyce-Codd / 5th Normal Form unless and until you find a compelling reason not to do that.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is yes, it makes sense to normalize data into 1NF (and beyond) in spite of how cheap disk space is.  In namy situations where you normalize by decomposing one table into two or more tables, the result takes more disk space than before.

The reason you want to put data in 1NF is to provide keyed access to all data.  If you don't have keyed access to all data, you will end up waiting for a full table scan where keyed access via an index would have given you the answer a hundred times faster.

1NF has nothing to do with NULLs.  A set of tables can be in 5NF (and therefore in 1NF) and still  contain NULLS.  Regarding NULLs themselves, the less said, the better.

Answer (score 0):

yes - store it in multiple tables.

your performance will in fact be better.

(note your example does not show how these two groups would be related, and you also do not show how to tell the difference between the two...)

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you have a really large set of data.

There are two scenarios that you would face

1. Fetching rows which have only common data
2. Fetching rows which have both common and specific data.

If you have single table with nullable columns the data retrieval could be fast as you will have no joins what so ever. But you might want to use 'isnull' in every query that you fire with specific columns in them.

Let us assume that you have significantly more attendees than organizers, in that case you would have significantly huge number of rows with specific columns having null values. This is waste of space. And also could hamper your query performance. In this case having separate table could be really helpful.